# startActivityForResult working in one activity but not working in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

**StartActivityForResult** is working in one activity but not working in other activity (accessing same functions).
I have 3 activities that are A,B & C. Both B & C are inherited from A. I'd written a code in parent activity and accessing it in both child activities, that same function is working in B but not working in C activity. I have checked line by line in debug mode onActivityResult never invoked in C activity.

Here is the code

Following is PhotoDialog function written in Parent activity A

```
public void PhotoDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.snapshot_dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    final TextView item1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogItem1);
    final TextView item2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogItem2);

    item1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    item2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strPrompt = "Choose a Snap Shot!";
            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            pickPhoto.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(pickPhoto, strPrompt),
                    GALLERY_REQUEST);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Following is the onClick listener written in parent activity.

```
public void btnCameraIconOnClick(View view) {
    PhotoDialog();
}
```

Here is xml of Activity B and C

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:onClick="btnCameraIconOnClick">  <---- Here is onClick 

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:background="@drawable/profile_pic_frame" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Please guide me what i am doing wrong. Why its working in B and not working in C. There is no difference in code of both activities.

**UPDATE**
C activity is with in tabview.

**EDIT**

```
<permission
    android:name="com.nthreads.out2b.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nthreads.out2b.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".activity.B"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.C"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>


</application>
```

This code is written on Both B and C from where i'm calling **PhotoDialog**

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case CAMERA_REQUEST:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Avatar camera mode was canceled.
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            //
            Bitmap cameraPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if (cameraPic != null) {
                try {
                    setProfilePic(cameraPic);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "saveAvatar() with camera image failed.",
                            e);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "OutOfMemory Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case GALLERY_REQUEST:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Avatar gallery request mode was canceled.
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // Determine which picture was chosen
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            if (photoUri != null) {
                try {
                    setProfilePic(loadImageFromUri(photoUri));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG",
                            "saveAvatar() with gallery picker failed.", e);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "OutOfMemory Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void setProfilePic(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap scaledPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
    profilePic.setImageBitmap(scaledPic);
}
```

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: I think there is no need to post Minifest here all activities are registered in Manifest file.

Comment: Yes, I want to see what parameters you have set in the manifest. It may be relevant.

Comment: Post code of `onActivityResult()` in Activity A, B and C

Comment: Thanks David for your quick replies, onActivityResult() is written in both B and C from where i'm calling PhotoDialog()
I mentioned that i'm calling C activity in tabview, is it causing that issue??

Comment: How do you know that `onActivityResult()` is not being called? Have you added logging? have you set a debugger breakpoint? If not, try those things to be sure.

Comment: Yes i checked via debugging and by using breakpoints. Its being called in B activity and not called in C activity which is called from one of tab.